# JAVA SCRIPT: send body from a GET request to a POST REQUEST - Not able to pass the body correctly

Tags: javascript

I am writting a JS script.

I am using GET requests to fetch a specific information, which is of JSON format.
I ma using a for loop to do so.
This work fine.

However at the end of each iteration, I need to send a POST request using the body from the previous get request.

I have difficulties to add the body from the get request to the POST request.

Here is a sample of my GET and POST requests: I am certain that the for loop is iterating correctly (not the same values).

```
          pm.sendRequest({
             url: requestUrl,
             method: 'GET',
             header: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
            },            
            }, function(err, getresponse) {
             if (err) {
             console.error(err);
             return;
             }
            console.log("response: ", getresponse.json());
            pm.environment.set('POSTResponseBody', JSON.stringify(getresponse.json()));
            
           });
setTimeout(function () {
           const POSTBody = pm.environment.get('POSTResponseBody');         
            
          
           const putRequestUrlPPR = 'https://postURL';   
               
           pm.sendRequest({
             url: putRequestUrlPPR,
             method: 'POST',
             header: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Accept': 'application/json',               
              },
             body: {
              raw: pm.environment.get('POSTBody')              
             }
            }, function(err, response) {
             if (err) {
             console.error(err);
             return;
            }
           console.log(response.json());
           }); //end of POST REQUEST
          },1000); // end of time out
```

With our without the timeout, I always send the same body.
How could I fix that?

Comment: A POST body would normally be url-encoded not JSON, are you sure the server is expecting JSON?  Also, the body of a GET request is normally empty, with variables appended to the URL like `/page-url.php?var1=value1&var2=value2` do you mean the server response body?

Comment: The behaviour of GET requests with bodies is (explicitly) undefined by the HTTP specification. You should not try to attach a body to a GET request. The library you are using to try to make the GET request with a body (which you haven’t specified) may not allow you to do that.

Comment: There are no Body added o the GET request.
However, there is a response body that I am using for the POST request in the "body request".
The issue thee is that I have a GET request that will generate ananswer, from which I can extract the "response  body" and put into a variable.

I tried several thing and the only way to pass it to the subsequent POST is to first 

``` pm.environment.set('POSTResponseBody', JSON.stringify(getresponse.json()));
```
As said as I am using a for loop on all that I have discovered that I end up always passing the same value to the POST request.

Comment: By the way, I have double check, the POST should be if it was a curl request:
curl -X 'POST' https://myposturl -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "key1": "a_stuff" ....}'

Comment: So to reply to both answer, I use the server reponsebody to the first GET request as a body for the POST request.